# Connecting Java to MySQL using mysql-connector-java-5.1.24

Tags: java, mysql, windows, jdbc

I'm reading through the JDBC API Tutorial and Reference 3/E (MAN, what a dry tome), and I'm having trouble connecting my Java program to my MySQL database using the MySQL Connector supplied by Oracle.

I've placed it in my folder

```
C:\Windows\Sun\Java\mysql-connector-java-5.1.24
```

and I've pointed my Workspace CLASSPATH in JGrasp to

```
C:\Windows\Sun\Java\mysql-connector-java-5.1.24\mysql-connector-java-5.1.24-bin.jar
```

I'm trying to connect to a database called "Coffee."  It definitely exists:

```
mysql> show databases;
+---------------------+
| Database            |
+---------------------+
| information_schema  |
| coffee              |
| mysql               |
| performance_schema  |
| phpmyadmin          |
+---------------------+
5 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

here's my Java code.  (If you have the book, I'm on page 88.  The only difference between my code and theirs is some comments, and that I'm going with MySQL.)

```
//first, import sql package
import java.sql.*;

//name class CreateCoffees
public class CreateCoffees { 

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:coffee";

        //declare variables 
        Connection conn;

        String createString =   "create table COFFEES " +
                                        "(COF_NAME varchar(32), " +
                                        "SUP_ID int, " +
                                        "PRICE float, " +
                                        "SALES int, " +
                                        "TOTAL int)";

        Statement stmt;


        //instructions
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        }
        catch(java.lang.ClassNotFoundException cnfe){
            System.out.println("Class Not Found - " + cnfe.getMessage());
        }       

        try{
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "");

            stmt = conn.createStatement();

            stmt.executeUpdate(createString);

            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
        }
        catch(SQLException sqle){
            System.out.println("SQL Exception: " + sqle.getMessage());
        }

    }

}
```

Everything compiles just fine, but when I run it, I throw the following SQLException:

```
SQL Exception: Cannot load connection class because of underlying exception: 'java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "coffee"'.
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?  Is there something I can run to otherwise test connectivity between Java and the database?  I'm fairly new to both.

Also, it should be noted that this is not homework.

EDIT:  It would seem the offending line of code is

```
 String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:coffee";
```

and should be changed to

```
 String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/coffee";
```

because coffee is a database and not a port.

I guess I need more of it.  Thanks to everyone who helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have "coffee" as your port number? You're supposed to have your mysql server port number there

```
jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:coffee
```

Hint: default port number is 3306. So try

```
jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/coffee
```

(Assuming your database name is coffee)

Comment: Indeed.  I've updated the OP to reflect your accurate information.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your connection URL is using `coffee` as the port. You should use something like:

```
jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/coffee
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the parser is getting confused and thinking that `coffee` is a port number.

Try this:

```
jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/coffee
```